# gcd and lcm for polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Let f, g, h ∈ F[X] with h a greatest common divisor of f and g. Show that

(i) f /h and g/h are coprime,

(ii) fg/h is a least common multiple of f and g.

Comment: Do you know how to prove this for integers instead of polynomials? The proof is deceptively similar.

Comment: I know how to for the first part